# android webrtc rotate VideoFrame

Tags: webrtc-android

I try below code to rotate VideoFrame by 90 degree but it doesn't work:

```
private VideoFrame rotateFrame(VideoFrame inVideoFrame) {
    VideoFrame outVideoFrame = new VideoFrame(
            inVideoFrame.getBuffer(),
            90, inVideoFrame.getTimestampNs());
    return outVideoFrame;
}
```

What's correct logic to rotate a videoFrame?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem but your code it's work for me.

I publish stream to Wowza Streaming Engine using webRTC and I try to debug my code while video frame publish to wowza. The orientation is `270`. When I received this orientation back from service. it's `0` I try to change it before pass this frame to `SurfaceViewRenderer`. It's work.

```
remoteVideoTrack.addSink {
   remoteView?.onFrame(VideoFrame(it.buffer, 270, -1))
 }
```